# Are Mathematica commands always supposed to check that Method -> name is valid?

Tags: options, optional-arguments

When calling a Mathematica command which accepts a `Method -> name` option, I always thought that if the `name` given is not a valid method name, then the command does not evaluate; i.e., the command always checks if the `Method` given is supported.

For example, this works, since the `Method` is valid:

```
ode = t y''[t] + y'[t] + 2 y[t] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[t], t, Method -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this will not work, since the `Method` name is wrong:

```
ode = t y''[t] + y'[t] + 2 y[t] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[t], t, Method -> "MickyMouse"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I was trying to find what `Method` can be used by `AsymptoticDSolveValue`, since it is not documented, and by chance I found it will accept any `Method` name I give it, and it still works.

```
ode = t y''[t] + y'[t] + 2 y[t] == 0;
ic = {y[0] -> C[1], y'[0] -> C[2]};
pt = 1;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[t], {t, pt, 3}, Method -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this also works:

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[t], {t, pt, 3}, Method -> "MickyMouse"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same answer as before. Since I am sure the `MickyMouse` method is not supported by `AsymptoticDSolveValue`, then it must be that not all commands do check the `Method` argument.

Is this buggy behaviour?

This makes one wonder if the `Method` name they supplied to a command was actually used, or was it ignored as in this example, and another method was used?

This is on 11.3, Windows 7.

Comment: @BobHanlon I see. I did not know this.  This makes sense. You could post this as answer and will accept it.

Comment: `Options`-checking is in general a headache. If there were any easy, built-in way to enforce `OptionValue` checks this type of thing would never come up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would expect a fully implemented/documented function to check the validity of the specified `Method`; however, since [`AsymptoticDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html) is marked as `[EXPERIMENTAL]` I would not assume that it is fully implemented/documented.

Comment: I haven't looked at the source code recently, but last I checked `Automatic` is currently the only implemented method. :)  Which is why it is not documented, and for now basically ignored.

Answer (score 12):

The other answer is completely correct (see my comment), but let me add some context.  For algorthmic functions, it is generally the case that we validate the method options and issue messages/fail (sometimes a fallback is used).  However, in "container" type functions, like `Graphics`/`Graphics3D`, we often don't validate them.  This is because they may be used by some layers and not others (for example, in `Graphics`, the value of `Method` might only affect front end rendering, and it is the front end which must understand it).  If they were validated, then every layer would have to know all the valid values, even if they were completely irrelevant.